# Find all possible combinations subject to group and person

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations

In reality my dataset is much longer, but here is a smaller example to show what I am trying to achieve.
In 'Set1', I have Amy, Meg and Ryan.  In 'Set2', I have only Amy. In 'Set3', I have Jim and Ryan.

For each set, I want a dataframe that lists all possible groups that can be created around a particular person - a person can be in a group with only themselves. E.g. For Set1, there are four different groups that can be created that include Amy:

Group 1:Amy,Meg,Ryan

Group 2:Amy

Group 3:Amy,Meg

Group 4:Amy,Ryan

Reproducible data

```
structure(list(Set = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3), Person = c("Amy", "Meg", 
"Ryan", "Amy", "Jim", "Ryan")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Set = structure(list(), class = 
c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Person = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function using some `tidyverse` stuff.

```
make_groups <- function(df) {
  require(tidyverse)
  n <- df %>% 
    group_by(Set) %>%
    summarize(n()) %>%
    select(-Set) %>%
    max()
   
  df2 <- df
  for(i in 1:(n-1)) {
    df2 <- inner_join(df2, df, by = "Set")
  }
  df2 %>% 
    rownames_to_column(var = "id") %>%
    nest_by(id, Set) %>%
    mutate(Group = list(str_c(unique(unlist(data)), collapse = ", "))) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(Set, Group) %>%
    distinct() %>%
    unnest(Group) %>%
    arrange(Set, Group)
}
```

So you can run `make_groups(data)` and get the following output:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 2
     Set Group         
   <dbl> <chr>         
 1     1 Amy           
 2     1 Amy, Meg      
 3     1 Amy, Meg, Ryan
 4     1 Amy, Ryan     
 5     1 Amy, Ryan, Meg
 6     1 Meg           
 7     1 Meg, Amy      
 8     1 Meg, Amy, Ryan
 9     1 Meg, Ryan     
10     1 Meg, Ryan, Amy
11     1 Ryan          
12     1 Ryan, Amy     
13     1 Ryan, Amy, Meg
14     1 Ryan, Meg     
15     1 Ryan, Meg, Amy
16     2 Amy           
17     3 Jim           
18     3 Jim, Ryan     
19     3 Ryan          
20     3 Ryan, Jim
```

Comment: I get the following : Warning message:
distinct() does not fully support columns of type `list`.
List elements are compared by reference, see ?distinct for details.
This affects the following columns:
- `Group`

Comment: I don't get this message. By the time it gets to `distinct()`, there should be no list columns. I am using `dplyr v 1.0.1` in `R v 4.0.2`. If you are using an older version of `dplyr`, perhaps that is the issue. If so, move `unnest(Group)` to before `distinct()`

Comment: I am using R v 4.0.2, tidyverse v 1.3.0, I have updated my dplyr so I'm using version 1.0.2.  When I run the code, using the reproducible data, it is not giving me the same output as you.  It says- `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument).  Why is this?

Comment: In the newer versions of `dplyr` the `summarise` verb has some new behavior with respect to groups. By default it drops the last level of grouping. In this case, it ungroups the data after summarizing, since there is only one group. This should not cause trouble for the function overall, since the steps after summarize do not need grouped data.

Comment: Here are my package versions: tidyverse 1.3.0, tidyr 1.1.1, dplyr 1.0.1, stringr 1.4.0. Is it possible that you have another package loaded that masks a function in one of these packages? What happens if you start a fresh R session and load only the tidyverse?

Comment: I did this and am still getting`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    Set Group              
  <dbl> <chr>              
1     1 Amy, Meg, Ryan, Jim
2     2 Amy, Meg, Ryan, Jim
3     3 Amy, Meg, Ryan, Jim

Comment: I get that message, too, but I still get an output tibble that is 20 x 2. I am not able to replicate the issue you are now having.